# Retornar un valor de una función con CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor

Tags: java

Tengo una función con un CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor, del cual necesito que al llegar a ejecutarse la función en el delayedExecutor, retorne un valor de la función principal.

Ejemplo:

```
public Map<String, Object> consultaPacienteDatos(Integer citaId, String nroDocumento) {

        CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).execute(() -> {
            return null;
        });
        
        return response;
    }
```

Al hacer lo que está en el ejemplo me da un error en "return null". Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: "Me da un error" -> Podrías ser un poco más explícito? Decir que algo no funciona da 0 información al respecto. Qué error exactamente?

Comment: En sí lo que necesito no va por el lado del error, solo necesito una forma de que desde el delayedExecutor retorne un valor para la función consultaPacienteDatos. Para ser un poco más específico sobre el error me dice "void methods cannot return a value", imagino que debe ser porque el return dentro del delayedExecutor solo tiene un alcance dentro del delayedExecutor y no de la función que lo engloba.

Comment: Según la documentación, el método `execute()` devuelve `void` con lo cual dentro del `execute(() => {})` no vas a poder poner tu return con nada... imagino que lo más fácil sería ahí dentro hacer `this.loQueSea = otraCosa;`, de esa manera no estás haciendo nada. O directamente llamar a otra función pasándole el valor que necesitas.

Comment: Entiendo, ya encontré otra forma de hacer lo que necesitaba. Gracias por la ayuda.